# How to justify expanding both f and g to find the limit of f/g?

Tags: taylor-expansion

If I can Taylor expand $f(x) = 2+ x+ x^2/2 +....$ and $g(x) = x/2 + x^2/3 + ....$ and I want to find the limit as $x\to0$, why is it that I can write

$$
\frac {f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac {2+ x+ x^2/2 + O(x^3)}{ x/2 + x^2/3 + O(x^3)} = \frac {2+ x+ x^2/2 }{ x/2 + x^2/3} + O(x^3)  \to 2.
$$

I can obviously see why it is intuitively true, but can someone explain the second equality rigorously?

Comment: It tends to $\pm \infty$ when $x\to \pm 0$, does'nt it ?

Answer (score 0):

Let consider
$$
f(x)= \sum_{i=0}^N a_i x^i + O\left(x^{N+1}\right)
$$
where $a_i=\frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}$ and
$$
g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^M b_j x^j + O\left(x^{M+1}\right)
$$

Let $I:=\min( i : a_i \ne 0)<N+1$ the order of $f(x)$ and similar for $J$, then
$$
\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= x^{I-J}\frac{\sum_{i= I}^N a_i x^{i-I} + O\left(x^{N+1-I}\right)}{\sum_{j= J}^M b_j x^{j-J} + O\left(x^{M+1-J}\right)}
$$
By taking the limit
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \lim_{x \to 0} x^{I-J} \frac{a_I}{b_J}
$$
where I have used that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} a_i x^{i-I}=0= \lim_{ x \to 0} b_j x^{j-J}
$$
for $i>I$ and $j>J$, $a_I \ne 0$ , $b_J \ne 0$ and the definition of big $O$

In your example $I=0$, $J=1$ and so
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \infty
$$
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= -\infty
$$